# Running pygame on VScode doesn't bring up graphical display

Tags: python

I've been working on creating simple games using pygame in VS code and the graphical display was working just fine, moved on to matplotlib,installed it and wrote a simple plot that I expected to show when I ran plt.show() but the code just ran showing no errors but not bringing up the graphical display, what's worse I tried running the simple pygame games I had built and although they run without showing any errors the graphical display also didn't come up.

-The terminal is running fine for print() actions
-i'm using windows 10 os

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.